# What is the use of as.numeric() in R?

Tags: r, time-series

this is Ex.1 on Page 252 in *Statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering* by Ruppert:

> This problem and the next use CRSP daily returns. First, get the data
>   and plot the ACF in two ways:

```
library(Ecdat)
data(CRSPday)
crsp=CRSPday[,7]
acf(crsp)
acf(as.numeric(crsp))
```

> Explain what “lag” means in the two ACF plots. Why does lag differ
>   between the plots?

I have run the code and got two acf plots:
[image]
[image]

It seems that only the x-axis tags of these plots are different. Why is that? Whst is the use of as.numeric in this case? Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you provide the info given by "str(crsp)"?

Comment: I suspect initially `csrp` is a `ts` type object, or similar. When plotting `acf` results, the lags are displayed relative to the time dimension associated with `csrp`, e.g. if the variable is quarterly, lag 1 would correspond to 1/4, lag 2 to 2/4, etc. When you apply `as.numeric`, the time dimension is dropped from `csrp` and the lags are measured simply as 1,2,3,...

Comment: Try: class(as.numeric(crsp)) and class(crsp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeremy Miles is correct.

There are many breeds of data.  Simple ones are integers, binary (T/F) variables, character arrays, and double-precision numbers.  R has entire zoos (pun intended) of other breeds and forms of data.  One of them is "time series".

You can verify that "crsp" is a time series object using the class function:

```
class(crsp)
```

If you want to determine which methods apply to this class, then use the "methods" function:

```
> methods(class=class(crsp))

 [1] [.ts*            [<-.ts*          aggregate.ts     as.data.frame.ts
 [5] cbind.ts*        cycle.ts*        diff.ts*         diffinv.ts*     
 [9] kernapply.ts*    lines.ts*        monthplot.ts*    na.omit.ts*     
[13] Ops.ts*          plot.ts          print.ts*        t.ts*           
[17] time.ts*         window.ts*       window<-.ts*
```

now if you want to compare it with a "numeric" object, then just use "as.numeric".

```
> class(as.numeric(crsp))

[1] "numeric"
```

you can also see the difference in available methods:

One of the features of a time series is that the time values are hidden inside of it.  When you convert it to a numeric, you trade those away for row indices.